# STM32 Swap Flash Banks. Purpose

Tags: stm32, arm, flash, sram

I was casually reading STM32 documentation and other materials out of self-education and self-development purposes and ran into bank swapping in system configuration (in referencep and/or programming manual). As for flash existing as two banks, I found a reason for it to be "for example you execute code from one bank, but write/erase the other bank". That is clear.

However, when I search for any explanation of WHY does one need to actually SWAP banks  - simply swap their addresses - I only come out with the results talking/asking about HOW to do it.

So the questions are: why swap Flash banks at all? And why swap SRAM banks? (or FMC banks for that matter)? In what kind of situations and with what kinds of tasks could any of that be really necessary?

Comment: Marketing materials always bring up field firmware updates there. To perform brain surgery on yourself you need a second brain to do it with, and also as a backup in case something goes wrong =)

Comment: Yes, for why there are dual banks. But not for why you need to swap addresses. I can't imagine a single situation where I would need to swap bank 1 and bank2 in terms of addresses

Comment: Swapping addresses is just part of that, no? To change which bank you are executing from.

Comment: why do I need to swap banks between, say, Cx00 and Dx00, if I can just execute code from Cx00 or Dx00 at will? EDIT: I'm not intimately familiar with how it actually happens. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Presumably so the code never needs to know what Bank it's executing from, so you don't have to check "global state". Think of double buffering.

Comment: Re-reading your post and comments are you asking why swapping addresses exists? Or are you asking why you need to have different bank addresses if you can swap addresses? There seems to be flip-flopping between which it is you are wondering about.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, that's what I'm asking. What is the purpose of that function

Comment: @IanBland yes, this makes sense to me, thanks; Edit: I will leave the question open for a bit in case someone has something big or important to say about it.

Comment: Which function? Address swapping? Because "*WHY does one need to actually SWAP banks - simply swap their addresses*" is asking why you need ever need to refer to different bank addresses when you can swap addresses. But swapping addresses lets your code be dumb and run the same. And the banks need different addresses so you can write to one while running off the other and to hash check.

Comment: I'm starting to get a feeling my question is dumber than it initially sounded in my head

Comment: @Ilya Asking why address swapping exists when you can just refer to unique bank addresses is the question that makes more sense. Asking why you need to have unique addresses for each bank when address swapping exists is the dumber question. Need to be able to write new firmware while running off the other and hash check it. Duuurr. heh

Comment: @Ilya no need to think in terms of dumb. We all learn what we know by asking questions. Some of them we answer ourselves, sometimes we need help from others.

Comment: @Ilya: Do you understand what "**position-independent code**" is and why most code, especially embedded firmware, is not compiled as "position-independent" ?   None of the above comments are probably making any sense if you did not know that position-independent code is special and inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very valuable for remote updates into Flash EPROM.

The application software will always run in the first FEPROM bank's address range. It is compiled/assembled for that address range. Within the software, its absolute jump instruction destinations, data tables and so on are required to be at specific and fixed memory addresses. The software cannot be relocated (moved to another memory address range and executed) without be recompiled/assembled for that address range.

For a remote update, it will:

- Obtain new application software, programming it into the second FEPROM bank.
- Swap the banks to put the second FEPROM into the first FEPROM's address range.
- Execute the now-first bank containing the remote update.

This needs great care to implement.